# How to remove extra column from csv of bulk api in JAVA

Tags: integration, java, bulk-api, csv

I am importing the data in to the salesforce using Bulk API. But I am facing this issues.

I am replacing the column header with the salesforce API name. But some of the heade which is not releted to the salesforce.

So how I can ignore or remove the column while importing the data using Bulk API. I am creating the temp file for the bulk data.

Please help me !!!!

Thank thank you in advance.

Piyush

Answer (score 1):

The Bulk API allows a [transformation spec](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_mapping.htm) to be defined for the upload process which is in itself a CSV file with these columns:

> - Salesforce Field - The Salesforce field you want to map to
> - Csv Header - The field in your import file you want to map
> - Value - A default value
> - Hint - Interpret Java format strings for date and time fields or define what is true using regular expressions for boolean fields

I suggest that you experiment with this mechanism to see if it allows columns to be dropped by simply not referencing them in the transformation spec. (My guess is that this will work but the documentation that I found says nothing on the subject and I have not tried it.)